# can't export Libgdx project

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, export

i have a game, written in libgdx, and i want to export it as a desktop runnable jar file. so i press export, runnable JAR file, i choose the project, write the export destination (with a .jar) pick Extract required libraries into generated JAR and export. all works till here. but when i open it, it just opens as a black screen and immediately closes itself. if i export it do android, my phone just won't recognize it as an app, and won't open it at all. what to do? i can show you the DesktopLauncher and android launcher if it helps:

```
package com.ak01.flappysquid.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.ak01.flappysquid.FlappySquid;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.height = 800;
        config.width = 480;
        config.title="flappy squid";
        new LwjglApplication(new FlappySquid(), config);
    }
}
```

android:

```
package com.ak01.flappysquid.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.ak01.flappysquid.FlappySquid;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new FlappySquid(), config);
    }
}
```

if you need any more pieces of information don't be afraid to ask.
when i run it from eclipse it does work.

BTW, to created the project by clicking import, gradle, gradle project.

Comment: Is it all fine while running project instead of executable exported jar?

Comment: How are you packaging the JAR exactly? Using an IDE? Gradle is used for packaging libGDX projects, the IDE typically doesn't do this without some tinkering here and there.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut what do you mean? if i run it in eclipse it will work.

Comment: @snh i just export it as i said in the first lines

Comment: That's not very helpful information. Does your computer have speech recognition that when you 'said' export, it exported? **How** did you go about exporting it?

Comment: @snh i right click the FlappySquid-desktop folder (in eclipse), choose export and pick runnable jar file

Comment: In that case, you should read up on Gradle and how to build projects using it, because you are building your project JAR incorrectly. flogy's answer contains two excellent links to the LibGDX documentation on Gradle and how to package your project, the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code looks fine. If you did not exit the game immediately inside your FlappySquid class, it should not close the window instantly ;)

Therefore, I guess the export is not done correctly. Try building it using "gralde build" instead of exporting. Then you should have the runnable jar and the apk for android in the related module folders. E.g. in the target or bin folder, dependinc on your project setup.

Here are some more informations on how to build the JAR or APK using gradle:

- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-desktop
- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-android

Comment: what do you mean by building it sing "gradle build"? i don't have it in the export options

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down voted other than it being more of a tip than an answer, but it seems to be a start. OP obviously isn't packaging the project as it should be packaged (Gradle).

Comment: I guess you have one of the latest versions of libGDX and therefore Gradle is used as building and dependency management tool. I don't know exactly how to do this in Eclipse, but you can run gradle from commandline using the two commands mentioned in the links in my post. Afterwards, your JAR/APK should be in the build folders of your modules.

Comment: You need to change directory to the root of your project before initiating a ```gradlew dekstop:build``` or the syntax according to your target device.